# Visio 2010/2013 page re-layout doesn't work if the page has a container shape with at least one child shape

Tags: c#, automation, visio

I'm recursively traversing a directed object graph to build a flow chart using the Visio 2010 Automation (SDK).

I successfully drop the shapes on the page and create their connectors, but when I layout the flowchart Visio misplaces to the bottom of the diagram the container shapes that have at least one child shape.

This problem with the Visio auto page layout also exists if the page is laid out from the UI (i.e. "Design" tab -> "Layout" group -> "Re-Layout Page" -> "Hierarchy").

To easily reproduce the error, in Visio 2010/2013:

1. Create a blank drawing
2. Add two basic shapes, from the "Basic Shapes" style sheet for example, let's call them B1 and B2 just for reference.
3. Place B1 about an inch above B2.
4. Select B1.
5. Add B1 to a container shape, let's call it C1. To add B1 to C1 select the left most container from the "Insert" tab -> "Diagrams    Parts" group -> "Container" in the toolbar.
6. Draw a connector from C1    to B2. The connector can be added from the "Home" tab -> "Tools" group -> "Connector" option in the toolbar. Right click the connector and select the "Format" -> "Line" option and add an "Arrow End" to the connector.
7. Re-Layout the page from the "Design tab" -> "Layout group" -> "Hierarchy" Top to Bottom option.

A) Notice how C1 is placed at the bottom of the diagram.

Being this a directed graph, shouldn't C1 be placed at the top of the diagram?

Do you know of any workaround in case this is a bug in the Visio 2010/2013 SDK?

If you remove B1 from C1 and Re-Layout the page again then C1 will be placed correctly at the top of the diagram.